# Prove that $y = x^3 + {5 \over 9} x $ is invertible

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, inverse-function

> Prove that $y = x^3 + {5 \over 9} x $ is invertible

How do I even express x in terms of y for cubic equations? For even powers I could use for example substitution, but no idea comes to my mind for odd ones.

I've asked W|A to solve for $x$ and it suggests that i should substitute $x$ with some $t+{ \lambda \over t}$, but that eventually brings an equation with even higher order and additionally there appears some constant $\lambda$ to be determined which seems to be way too complicated. I believe there exists a simpler solution.

**UPD**:

I'm not supposed to use derivative or other methods from "calculus".

So eventually this comes to a couple of questions:

> 1. Is there a simpler way of expressing $x$ in terms of $y$ than the above?
> 2. Is it possible to generalize the solution for the polynomials of the following kind: $y = x^n + px + q$ where $n$ is odd; $n, p>0$ and $q \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: For simple invertibility there is no need to write out the inverse explicitly.  $y'=3x^2+\frac 59>0$ so this function is strictly increasing, hence invertible.

Comment: @lulu thanks for the answer, i've just updated my question. Unfortunately the author of the problem assumes this may be done without using derivatives. I should've been more precise in the question.

Comment: $x^3$ is increasing, $x$ is increasing, so $y=x^3+\frac{5}{9}x$ is also increasing

Comment: You certainly do not need derivatives to see that $y$ is strictly increasing.  It's the sum of two increasing functions!

Comment: @lulu, oh, how haven't i noticed that, it's clear now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^3+\frac{5}{9} x$. Then, for reals $a\neq b$, $$f(a)=f(b) \iff a^3-b^3 +\frac{5}{9}(a-b)=0 \iff (a-b)\left(a^2+ab+b^2+\frac{5}{9}\right)=0.$$
But
$$\left(a^2+ab+b^2+\frac{5}{9}\right) = \left(a+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3b^2}{4}+\frac{5}{9}>0.$$
Consequently, $a=b$, a contradiction.

Comment: You have to show that it is surjective even though it's trivial?

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of function $x\mapsto x^3+\frac59x$ is positive for every $x$, so the function is monotonically increasing. Further it is continuous with $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=-\infty$.

Then with intermediate value theorem it can be proved that the function is surjective, and the fact that is monotically increasing tells us directly that it is injective as well.

This together proves that the function is bijective, or equivalently has an inverse.